# Python filter dataframe with condition and column

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

i'm curious if it's possible to filter a pandas DataFrame by column and a condition. Or do i have to do it with two steps.

So my basic idea is to do:

```
 df['cluster' & (df['Type'] == 't')]
```

Or is there no overhead achieving this by two steps like:

```
tmp = df[df['Type'] == 't']
tmp = tmp[df['Type']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.loc[df['Type'] == 't', 'cluster']
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what OP need :)

Comment: If add some data sample solution will be better :)

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I somehow couldn't find this way to filter the data.